# Restrict suggestions from ESRI ArcGIS REST API to US addresses only

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geocoding, arcgis-online

I am wondering if there is a way to restrict [esri arcgis REST API](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Working_with_suggestions/02r300000238000000/) to suggest only US addresses.

Combination of location & distance parameters prioritizes the results, but that doesn't restrict suggestions to an area.

I tried setting the [bbox](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Single_input_field_geocoding/02r300000015000000/) parameter, but looks like it is only supported for find api and not for suggest.

SO, how do I make the arcgis suggestions restrict to only US addresses ??

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question. The [geocoder API reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geocoder.html) has a sourceCountry option:

> **sourceCountry:** Country code to use for the search. Using a
>   country code can improve location search performance. Specify the
>   sourceCountry using a valid country code from [this list](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Service_coverage/02r300000018000000).

However, I can't get this to work. I tried the [Geocoder Sample](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=locator_simple) in the sandbox, using these options:

```
geocoder = new Geocoder({ 
  map: map,
  sourceCountry: "AUS",
  autoComplete: true
}, "search");
```

Searching on "Windsor" returns a match within Detroit, and not the expected Windors within Australia (there are at least a couple).

So unless I'm using the option incorrectly, it looks like there's a problem with the sourceCountry parameter in the geocoder, which is preventing the ability to restrict suggestions based on country. It might be worth submitting a bug report on this.

Comment: http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest?text=petersburg&outFields=*&bbox=-103.650463,25.239370,-36.150463,49.606894&location=-115.144989,36.167361&distance=4000&forStorage=false&f=pjson&sourceCountry=USA.         This doesn't restrict search to USA.

Comment: you must have sourceCountry as part of arcgisGeocoder object. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geocoder-amd.html

Comment: @user30735 re "you must have sourceCountry as part of arcgisGeocoder object" - that's what I thought my code above should be doing?

Comment: i meant sourceCountry should be part of an arcgisGeocoder object which is property of params object. like so, geocoder = new esri.dijit.Geocoder({
          map: map,
          autoComplete: true,
          **arcgisGeocoder**: {
     /*url:"http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer",*/
     name:"address search",
     outFields: "StAddr,City,Region,Postal",
     placeholder: "Enter city, state or zip code",
     sourceCountry: "USA"
          }
        },"search");

Comment: @user30735 according to [the doco](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geocoder.html#geocoder1) it's the other way around - the map is a property of the geocoder: `var geocoder = new esri.dijit.Geocoder({map: map },"search");`

Answer (score 2):

Currently the Suggest operation (part of the ArcGIS Online REST API) does not support the countryCode or searchExtent parameters. Support for searchExtent will be added as part of the next ArcGIS Online update, while countryCode will be added in a subsequent release.